# How can I update Session values without refreshing my page in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

'm very new to ASP.NET MVC and web development and I don't know how I update Session values without refreshing the whole page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using JavaScript for example. Just make a request calling some controller method that will update your session. You can use JQuery, it's even easier that way.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Mark as answer if it's an answer :)